# How can I check for multiple conditions before I make format changes

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the piece of code I am working with:

```
Range("n10:n999").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="-100"
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38

Range("o10:o999").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="-0.05"
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
```

It is an older piece of coding in a macro but I am trying to adjust this to check each of these columns for one more condition.  Right now, column n is checked to see if the cell value is -$100 or less and if it is it is bolded and the cell turns purple (it looks purple to me...).  Column p is checked to see if the percentage amount is -5% or less and if it is it is bolded and the cell turns purple.  FOR BOTH COLUMNS I want to check, also, to see if, for column n, the amount is positive $100 or more and for column p, if the percentage is 5% or greater.

Comment: try with macro recorder, you will get your code within few sec...

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional formating under the home tab-styles section, would be the easiest possible way.  Once in the conditional formating tab you can insert the equation that will say

```
=If (*cell*<=-100,1,0)
```

then you can add all the specifications to the cell you want to make like color or being bold.  This is the easiest way especialy if you have a static range.  If your range is dynamic, or allways growing then you should look at VBA.

Comment: Since I am rusty with VBScript and this particular script is really old (I think) and am not totally sure of the syntax, etc.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have been looking at the other operators like "not between" or something like that that might work in this format (old format I know) but if it is "not between" (don't know the exact syntax) do I change the formula to be something like Formula1:="-100 and 100"?  That is is syntax that I am struggling with.  Thanks for the idea, I will look into that too!